# Host name may not be null. I am using Http-post method to get response from webservice

Tags: json, web-services, http-post

Here is the code I am using to get response from web service.getJSONFromUrl method used to get response from the web service.

I am getting error that java.lang.IllegalStateException,Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet

```
final String TAG = "JsonParser.java";

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) 
{

    // make HTTP request
    try 
{

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, 
"iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

Comment: What arguments are you supplying to `getJSONFromUrl`? Where is the stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks For Reply. The argument I pass is URL of my Web service, that is at Local Host.And I got The error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet@41575008

Comment: You're probably not using the full addressing scheme. Are you using *http://localhost:8080/YourService*, complete with protocol?

Comment: "http://192.168.0.102:8080/RESTfulWS/rest/UserInfoService/Json" This is the URL I am Using.